# Owerwrite Parent class variable through its Subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

Parent class:

> account.rb

```
class Account
    attr_reader :owner, :interest
    attr_accessor :funds

    def initialize(args)
        @funds = args[:funds]
        @owner = args[:owner]
        @interest = 0.01
    end
end
```

> saving_account.rb

```
class SavingAccount < Account
    attr_reader :interest
    def initialize(args)
        @interest = 0.05
        super(args)
    end
end
```

When I run

```
saving_acc = SavingAccount.new(funds: 10000, owner: "Jack")
assert_equal(0.05, saving_acc.interest)
```

I get:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `interests' for #<SavingAccount:0x007fa711853828>
>   tests/saving_account_test.rb:13:in`test_interests'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change order of order of calling `super` before the assignment.

```
class SavingAccount < Account
    attr_reader :interest
    def initialize(args)
        super(args)
        @interest = 0.05
    end
end
```

BTW, that's a typo that cause the error.

```
assert_equal(0.05, saving_acc.interests)
                                      ^
```

In addition to that, `@interest` is not a class variable, but a instance variable.

Comment: You are right, apart from the typo, everything has been solved by moving super(args)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing 's'

```
 saving_acc = SavingAccount.new(funds: 10000, owner: "Jack")
 assert_equal(0.05, saving_acc.interest)
```